# Panels are not lining up

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to line up three panels as seen in the screenshot but everything I've tried hasn't fixed the problem. I've tried reducing the panels widths to 30% and floating them, and I have used display:inline and still the problem persists. Any Ideas what is causing this ?

[Problem Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6sOo.jpg)

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="hscontent">
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns" id="skinny">
        <div class="panela">
            <img class="panelimg" src="Images/HS-TAB-TOP-A.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="panel" background-color:#2b4e24;>
            <div class="tabhead"><h5 class="taba">Our virtual tour !</h5></div>
            </br>
            <p class="tabpara">Take a virtual tour of the Horseshoe Bar and Restaurant and see for  
            yourself its unique, alluring and enchanting interior and atmosphere . It’s rich history and 
            heritage combines in a warm and charming blend that mixes traditional Irish decor with ornate   
            old World elegance.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns" id="skinny">
        <div class="panela">
            <img class="panelimg" src="Images/HS-TAB-TOP-B.png" />
        </div>
            <div class="panel" background-color:#2b4e24;>
                <div class="tabhead"><h5 class="tabb">See our menus</h5></div>
                </br>
                <div class="hstabs">
                    <a href="default.asp"><span class="tabby">Bar Menu</span></a>
                    <a href="default.asp"><span class="tabby">Evening Menu</span></a>
                    <a href="default.asp"><span class="tabby">Wine Menu</span></a>
                    <a href="default.asp"><span class="tabby">Whiskey Menu</span></a>
                    <a href="default.asp"><span class="tabby">Gin Menu</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns" id="skinny">
    <div class="panela">
      <img class="panelimg" src="Images/HS-TAB-TOP-C.png" /></div>
        <div class="panel" background-color:#2b4e24;>
            <div class="tabhead"><h5 class="taba">Our take on trad</h5></div>
            </br>
            <p class="tabpara">At one of the Horseshoe’s music sessions you’ll see and hear all of the 
            splendour that is the Irish traditional music session. A local gathering of talented, and soulful 
            musicians spinning tunes that capture all of the joy, sorrow, humour and heart of a Irish 
            traditional music set. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

RELEVANT CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    width:1200px;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

#hsback {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 1320px;
    background-image: url('../Images/HSBACK-WIDE.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    padding-right: auto;
    padding-left: auto;
}

#hscontent {
    margin-top:-640px;
}

#skinny {
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}

.panela {
    display:inline;
}

panelimg {
    width: 100%;
}

hr.style1{
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.panel {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #2b4e24;
    width: 87%;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px #000000;
}

.panela img {
    overflow:visible;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.panela a {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.taba {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.0;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size: 2.1rem;
    margin-top:0.5rem;
    text-align:center;
    width:98%;
    border-bottom: 1px Solid #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom: 0.3rem;
}

.tabb {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.0;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size: 2.1rem;
    margin-top:0.5rem;
    text-align:center;
    width:98%;
    border-bottom: 1px Solid #FFFFFF ;
    padding-bottom: 0.3rem;
}

.tabhead {
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.tabpara {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 1.3;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: -70px;
    word-spacing: -2;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding:3px;
    width:98%;
}

.tabcolor {
    background-color: #2b4e24;
}

.hstabs {
    margin-top: -3.7rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.90rem;
}

.tabby {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 0.15rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.15rem;
    display:block;
}

.tabby {
        text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: your problem page link isn't working.  Also, set this up as a working snippet and make it easier for us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues that could be contributing:

- You're using invalid tags - `</br>` is not a tag. I assume you meant `<br/>`
- The HTML structure is invalid. There are incorrectly nested tags and missing closing tags. Please put your HTML through a parser to make sure the HTML is correct. I have made some corrections below.

```css
body {
  width: 1200px;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

#hsback {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1320px;
  background-image: url('../Images/HSBACK-WIDE.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  padding-right: auto;
  padding-left: auto;
}

#hscontent {
  margin-top: -640px;
}

.top-bar {
  padding: 2.0rem;
  background-image: url('../Images/Menuback-TRANS.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.top-bar li {
  padding-top: 3.0rem;
  padding-bottom: 2.0rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.top-bar li {
  float: left;
}


/* Make CSS more specific */

.top-bar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
}

.menulogo img {
  float: left;
}

#skinny {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.panela {
  display: inline;
}

panelimg {
  width: 100%;
}

hr.style1 {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.panel {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #2b4e24;
  width: 87%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px #000000;
}

.panela img {
  overflow: visible;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.panela a {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.taba {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.0;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 98%;
  border-bottom: 1px Solid #FFFFFF;
  padding-bottom: 0.3rem;
}

.tabb {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.0;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 98%;
  border-bottom: 1px Solid #FFFFFF;
  padding-bottom: 0.3rem;
}

.tabhead {
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.tabpara {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -70px;
  word-spacing: -2;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 98%;
}

.tabcolor {
  background-color: #2b4e24;
}

.hstabs {
  margin-top: -3.7rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.90rem;
}

.tabby {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 0.15rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.15rem;
  display: block;
}

.tabby {
  text-align: center;
}

#whiskeyback {
  background: url("../Images/NU-WHISKEY-BACK.jpg")!important;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.0rem;
}

.whiskey {
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  line-height: 3.0rem;
  color: #e8d789;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 14px #e8d789;
  padding: 0.8rem;
}

.whiskeytitle {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: auto;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  padding-left: auto;
}

.whiskeyparabig {
  color: #f9f8fd;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 2.5rem;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
}

.whiskeypara {
  color: #f9f8fd;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0.45rem;
  padding-bottom: 4.2rem;
  padding-right: 3.2rem;
  padding-left: 3.6rem;
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Make CSS more specific */


/*img {
    display:inline;
}*/

#foota {
  background-image: url('../Images/FOOTER-BACK-BIG.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
}

#footmenu {
  padding-top: 2.0rem;
  padding-bottom: 2.0rem;
}

#footmenua {
  padding-top: 1.0rem;
  padding-bottom: 2.0rem;
  margin-left: 0.1rem;
  margin-top: -3.8rem;
}

.footlink {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.0rem;
  margin-left: 1.0rem;
  color: #f9f8fd;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}

.footlinka {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.0rem;
  margin-left: 1.0rem;
  color: #f9f8fd;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}

.footpic {
  margin-top: -5.0rem;
  padding-right: 1.0rem;
}

#floatfoot {
  display: inline;
}

#floatfoot img {
  margin-top: -1.0rem;
}

.footlogo {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="row" id="hsback">
    <div class="top-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Special Offers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rooms</a></li>
      </ul>
      <img class="menulogo" src="Images/VINTAGE-SIGN-3A2.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="row" id="hscontent">
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns">
    <div class="panela">
      <img class="panelimg" src="Images/HS-TAB-TOP-A.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="panel" background-color:#2b4e24;>
      <div class="tabhead">
        <h5 class="taba">Our virtual tour !</h5>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <p class="tabpara">Take a virtual tour of the Horseshoe Bar and Restaurant and see for yourself its unique, alluring and enchanting interior and atmosphere . It’s rich history and heritage combines in a warm and charming blend that mixes traditional Irish decor with
        ornate old World elegance.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns" id="skinny">
    <div class="panela">
      <img class="panelimg" src="Images/HS-TAB-TOP-B.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="panel" background-color:#2b4e24;>
      <div class="tabhead">
        <h5 class="tabb">See our menus</h5>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="hstabs">
        <a href="default.asp"><span class="tabby">Bar Menu</span></a>
        <a href="default.asp"><span class="tabby">Evening Menu</span></a>
        <a href="default.asp"><span class="tabby">Wine Menu</span></a>
        <a href="default.asp"><span class="tabby">Whiskey Menu</span></a>
        <a href="default.asp"><span class="tabby">Gin Menu</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns">
    <div class="panela">
      <img class="panelimg" src="Images/HS-TAB-TOP-C.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="panel" background-color:#2b4e24;>
      <div class="tabhead">
        <h5 class="taba">Our take on trad</h5>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <p class="tabpara">At one of the Horseshoe’s music sessions you’ll see and hear all of the splendour that is the Irish traditional music session. A local gathering of talented, and soulful musicians spinning tunes that capture all of the joy, sorrow, humour and heart
        of a Irish traditional music set. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row" id="whiskeyback">
  <div class="small-12 medium-6 medium-offset-6 large-5 large-offset-7 columns">
    <img class="whiskeytitle" src="Images/WHISKEY-GOLD-3.png" />
    <p class="whiskeyparabig">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
    <p class="whiskeypara">amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="row" id="foota">
    <div class="row" id="footmenu">
      <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
        <img class="footlogo" src="Images/BEHAN'S-FOOTER-LOGO-GOLD-SMALL.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="footmenua">
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns">
        <a href=" default.asp "><span class="footlink ">Our Menus</span></a>
        <a class="footlink " href="default.asp ">Testimonials</a>
        <a class="footlink " href="default.asp ">Rooms</a>
        <be/>
        <a class="footlinka " href="default.asp ">Take a Tour</a>
        <a class="footlinka " href="default.asp ">Our Sessions</a>
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-3 medium-offset-3 large-3 large-offset-3 columns" id="floatfoot">
        <img class="footpic" src="Images/Trip-Advisor-Smallest.png" />
        <img class="footpic" src="Images/facebook-Smallest.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Brett. It's the first time I've tried nesting divs. That seems to be working fine now. Would it be correct to say that the .hsback class div can be closed off after closing .topbar as the background image size has been explicitly set ? And that if the background were being filled out by content it would close after the third column is closed off ?

Comment: Any time you have an opening tag (unless its a rare self-closing tag like `<br/>`) you would need a closing tag. And the nesting needs to be valid. Meaning you can't do `<header><div></header></div>` - because the `header` is being closed before the child `div` is being closed. If you wanted a background to cover multiple elements it would most likely be moved up the DOM tree so it was at root level or near it. The nesting of the HTML tags gives you a good indication of how it works - I cleaned it up to make it more obvious.

Comment: By higher up the DOM tree you mean attaching it to say, the body of the page or a wrapper/container ? I would have done that in this case only I already had a separate background image lower down the page. Overall, yeah I think I'm ok, thanks for your time on this Brett.

Comment: Yes, you could move the element containing the background image to be a direct child of `body`. Don't forget to the [mark the solution that answers your question as the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).